# I got an error when running npm run watch. How to fixed this error. Please help me

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

ERROR in ./resources/js/App.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> 

|     
|

webpack compiled with 4 errors

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For better understanding of the question, i would request you to add complete error message to the description and also point out what environment and config you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.